# Caracter Repetido

Tags: python, python-requests

Escreva a função “repetido” que recebe uma String por parâmetro e retorna false caso
a String não possua caracteres repetidos (que aparece mais de uma vez, independente da
posição) ou true caso algum caracter esteja repetido.
Monte também um trecho de código para testar a função.

Exemplo:
r = repetido("aula"); /*retorna true pois o 'a' se repete.*/

r = repetido("aeiou"); /*retorna false pois nenhum caracter se repete*/

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Apesar de não ser 100% idêntica, a pergunta indicada acima no box azul tem a solução, basta adaptá-la: use uma das respostas e veja se alguma letra ocorre mais de uma vez

Answer (score -2):

A partir da seguinte função irás conseguir ter a funcionalidade que desejas. Basicamente o for irá "checkar" cada letra da palavra enviada para a função, se a letra já estiver na lista, quer dizer que é repetida, se não quer dizer que é uma letra diferente das outras.

```
def repetido(palavra):
    letras = []
    for i in palavra:
        if i not in letras:
            letras.append(i)
        else:
            return True
    return False

print(repetido('aula'))
```

Output: True